# The size of file displayed on the Apple is different from the capacity displayed on the command line ls -lh

Tags: macos, shell

Systerm: MacOs
I created the file whose size is 800M using go,when I use the command line: ls -lh, It shows 763M.However the Apple Finder shows 800M..What happend and Why?

Comment: I have a USB stick, where all files are shown by finder having the exactly same size, while `ls -l` shows different sizes. They all are fairly small sizes (a few KB). My guess is that the size shown by Finder reflects the part used on disk for the file, while `ls` of course needs to report the "true" file size. Since space on disk is allocated in blocks, these numbers differ. However, there must be something more on it, because I don't see the effect on every device. Maybe it also depends on the file system.